# How to generate formkey in Magento and send a POST request?

Tags: magento-1.9, form-key, post-data

Magento uses some sort of form key to send POST data. I want to send POST data to a controller in Magento and receive it.  How do I do that?

Comment: I am new to Magento. Can I do this from an API? If so should I include some class or file? Can you share some sample code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey()` to get a valid form key.